# use SeamlessM4Tv2Model, I want to slow down the rate of speech of audio output

Tags: python, pytorch, text-to-speech, huggingface

```
text_inputs = processor(text="I have a daughter 2 years old, I wanted her name to be Hương Ly", src_lang="eng", return_tensors="pt").to(device)
audio_array = model.generate(**text_inputs, tgt_lang=language)[0].cpu().numpy().squeeze()
file_path = 'audio_from_text.wav'
sf.write(file_path, audio_array, 16000)
```

[doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/seamless_m4t_v2)
[[ex](https://huggingface.co/spaces/Imadsarvm/Sarvm_Audio_Translation/resolve/b5b7fa364f8c567c4eb330583f673cd4c600976b/app.py?download=true)]

it has returned a 3 seconds audio

I try adding `speech_temperature=0.2` or `speech_do_sample=True` to `generate()` but there is no change, it still has returned a 3 seconds audio, for example, I want to change the rate of speech so it will be 5 seconds audio
any ideal ?